# Improving clarity and style of this "Document at a time" algorithm

Tags: erlang

I've created a module that implements a basic "Document at a time" algorithm for inverted index querying ([more background here](http://fontoura.org/papers/vldb2011.pdf)). There are many algorithm improvements possible, but I'm now interested in feedback on the structure of the Erlang code, specifically:

- Unneeded verbosity / code
- Erlang 'style' mistakes
- Things that can be done more elegantly
- (and yes, it's missing documentation)

```
-module(search_daat).

-export([get_top/2]).

-record(
  heap, 
    { 
      heap :: list({integer(), integer()}), 
      min_score :: integer()
    }
  ).

-record(
  postings,
    {   
      docs :: list({integer(),integer()}),
      max_score :: integer(),
      name :: string()
      }
  ).


-spec get_top(
        integer(),
        list(#postings{})
       ) -> #heap{}.
get_top(N, Postings) ->
    get_top(N, Postings, #heap{ heap = [], min_score = 0}, 0, 0).

-spec get_top(
        integer(),
        list(#postings{}),
        #heap{},
        integer(),
        integer()
       ) -> #heap{}.
get_top(N, Postings, Heap, CurrentDocId, UpperBound) ->
    Result = next(Postings, CurrentDocId, UpperBound),
    case Result of
        {error, not_found} ->
            Heap;
        {{NextDocId, _Score}, NewPostings} ->
            FullScore = full_score(NextDocId, NewPostings),
            NewHeap = heap_insert(Heap, N, NextDocId, FullScore),
            get_top(N, NewPostings, NewHeap, NextDocId, NewHeap#heap.min_score)
    end.

-spec heap_insert(#heap{}, integer(), integer(), integer()) -> #heap{}.
heap_insert(Heap, MaxHeapSize, DocId, FullScore) ->
    case length(Heap#heap.heap) < MaxHeapSize of
        true ->
            Heap1 = Heap#heap.heap ++ [{DocId, FullScore}],
            Heap2 = [{_,MinScore} | _Rest] = lists:keysort(2, Heap1),
            Heap#heap{ heap = Heap2, min_score = MinScore};
        false ->
            case Heap#heap.min_score > FullScore of
                true ->
                    Heap;
                false ->
                    Heap1 = lists:keydelete(
                              Heap#heap.min_score, 
                              2,
                              Heap#heap.heap
                             ) ++ [{DocId, FullScore}],
                    Heap2 = [{_, MinScore} | _Rest] = lists:keysort(2, Heap1),
                    Heap#heap{ heap = Heap2, min_score = MinScore}
                end
    end.

-spec full_score(integer(), list(#postings{})) -> integer().     
full_score(DocId, Postings) ->
    lists:foldl(fun(Posting, Acc) ->
                      [{CurrentDocId, Score} | _] = Posting#postings.docs,
                      case CurrentDocId == DocId of
                          true ->
                              Acc + Score;
                          false ->
                              Acc
                      end
                end,
                0,
                Postings).

-spec next(
        list(#postings{}),
        integer(),
        integer()
       ) -> {error, not_found} | {{integer(), integer()}, list(#postings{})}.
next(Postings, CurrentDocId, UpperBound) ->
    case find_pivot(Postings, UpperBound) of
        {error, not_found} -> {error, not_found};
        Pivot -> 
            [{PivotDocId, PivotDocScore} | _] = Pivot#postings.docs,
            [HeadPosting | _Rest] = Postings,
            [{HeadPostingDocId, _}| _] = HeadPosting#postings.docs,
            case PivotDocId =< CurrentDocId of
                true -> 
                    NewPostings = skip_to(Postings, CurrentDocId + 1),
                    next(NewPostings, CurrentDocId, UpperBound);
                false -> case PivotDocId == HeadPostingDocId of
                             true -> 
                                 {{PivotDocId, PivotDocScore}, Postings};
                             false -> 
                                 NewPostings = skip_to(Postings, PivotDocId),
                                 next(NewPostings, CurrentDocId, UpperBound)
                         end
            end
    end.

-spec skip_to(list(#postings{}), integer()) -> list(#postings{}).                                 
skip_to([HeadPosting | Postings], SkipToDocId) ->
    [_ | Docs] = HeadPosting#postings.docs,
    case skip_to(Docs, HeadPosting, SkipToDocId) of
        {error, no_docs_left} -> Postings; %% remove head
        NewHeadPosting -> 
            sort_by_head([NewHeadPosting | Postings])
    end.

-spec skip_to(
        list({integer(),integer()}),
        list(#postings{}),
        integer()
       ) -> {error, no_docs_left} | #postings{}. 
skip_to([], Posting, SkipToDocId) ->
    {error, no_docs_left};
skip_to([{DocId, Score} | NewDocs], Posting, SkipToDocId) ->
    case DocId >= SkipToDocId of
        true ->
            #postings{ 
          docs = [{DocId, Score} | NewDocs], 
          max_score = Posting#postings.max_score, 
          name = Posting#postings.name 
         };
        false ->
            skip_to(NewDocs, Posting, SkipToDocId)
    end.                         

-spec find_pivot(
        list(#postings{}),
        integer()
       ) -> {error, not_found} | #postings{}.
find_pivot(Postings, UpperBound) ->
    find_pivot(Postings, UpperBound, 0).

-spec find_pivot(
        list(#postings{}),
        integer(),
        integer()) -> {error, not_found} | #postings{}. 
find_pivot([], UpperBound, _TestBound) ->
    {error, not_found};
find_pivot([Posting | Postings], UpperBound, TestBound) ->
    Weight = 1,
    NewTestBound = TestBound + Weight * Posting#postings.max_score,
    case NewTestBound >= UpperBound of
        true -> Posting;
        false -> find_pivot(Postings, UpperBound, NewTestBound)
    end.

-spec sort_by_head(list(#postings{})) -> list(#postings{}).
sort_by_head(Postings) ->
    lists:sort(
               fun(
                 P1, P2
                ) ->
                       [{DocId1, _} | _] = P1#postings.docs,
                       [{DocId2, _} | _] = P2#postings.docs,
                       DocId1 =< DocId2
               end,
      Postings
     ).
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure writing explicit type specifications is idiomatic Erlang. In all programming languages that support inference, type specifications are used in specific cases, eg. when you want to restrict the possibles types, but not by default. Even if the [doc on specifications](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html) explain a few advantages, the [Erlang programming rules](http://www.erlang.se/doc/programming_rules.shtml) don't even mention it. Make sure you know why you're using them!

```
-record(
  postings,
    {   
      docs :: list({integer(),integer()}),
      max_score :: integer(),
      name :: string()
      }
  ).
```

Please document your records: types help but I also want to know that the first integer is the document id, and that the second integer is the score, and I want to know it in the record definition. :) Also, watch out your indentation for the last brace.

Names: `heap` describes the container, but not what it contains: be more specific. The same applies for `next`, I think you could name it `nextposting` or `next_posting`, but I'm not sure. [Names are hard!](http://www.erlang.se/doc/programming_rules.shtml#REF10726)

In `full_score`, I wouldn't alter the logic of your `foldl` call just to remove the score of `DocId`. I would pass the whole tuple to `full_score`, and remove the score after the sum has been made. More generally, it makes sense to have function interfaces that get one or multiple 'document' rather than just document ids just because you need that right now. Defining a specific document type, for example, would help too.

If you changed `full_score` to get a full document including its score, you can call `lists:map` to retrieve scores and `lists:sum` to get the sum. That would probably be easier to read but would require two passes: that's up to you!